# where does Android Studio look for imported packages?

Tags: android-studio, import, package

I am trying to understand where AS finds everything it suppose to import

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
```

I looked in

C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Android

to no avail.

although i found few paths that had 'google' or 'android' in them but nothing was a match.
so i still don't understand where all those packages are hiding.
what am i missing?
thank you

Comment: May be that it looks in its API?!

Comment: ok, and where is that API located on my computer?

Comment: It's Android internal stuff. You don't have to mess with it

Comment: ok. now how do i +1 you? or check you in green for the best answer?

Comment: You can't, since I didn't answer. I only commented. ;)